# Google lists websites with the suffix ""?from=xiaodiaomao.com""

Tags: url, google-search, google-search-console

Google list many websites, mine included, with the suffix:

```
"?from=xiaodiaomao.com"
```

I have no idea where that comes from. I don't have any reference to 'xiaodiaomao' in my website. Yesterday I noticed a warning in my Google Search Console, pointing to that link because it contains an 'escaped fragment'.

Does anyone know what is this link?

Can I do anything to prevent that this link is listed in Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick overlook looks, that it's some kind of Chinese search or something. Keep in mind that all content in most of the cases are available if you add a parameter at the end of URL. Don't know what is the goal of this site, but there is a link on that website to your website which adds the ending parameter. So, Google crawls that website and that URL with their random parameter.

All these websites which are indexed in Google, are without Canonical Link tags. Please implement proper canonical link tag and then search engines won't index these duplicate contents with random parameters etc.